# Error in authorize function nextauthjs typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'm trying to use the credentials provider in nextAuth, NextJS application("next": "13.5.4", "next-auth": "^4.23.2"). I am writing this in typescript, and facing issues in getting the function correctly.

here is my `api\auth\[...nextauth]\route.ts` file

```
CredentialsProvider({
        name: 'credentials',
        credentials: {},

        async authorize(credentials: any) {
            const {email, password} = credentials

            try {
                const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                    where: {
                        email: email
                    }
                })

                if (!user) {
                    return null
                }

                const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                if (!passwordMatch) {
                    return null
                }

                return user
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("ERROR AuthOptions: ", error);                    
            }
        },
    }),
```

this is the error I am getting

```
Type '(credentials: any) => Promise<{ id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; telephone: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<never, string>, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable<User>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; telephone: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<User>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; telephone: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<User>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = { id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; telephone: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: { id: number; firstName: string; ... 5 more ...; updatedAt: Date; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>, onrejected?: (reason: an...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = User, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: User) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) => PromiseLike<...>'.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type '{ id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; email: string; password: string; telephone: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'User'.
                Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
                  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[image]

My ts.config file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to usage of wrong signature for method `authorize`.

Two possible fixes:

1. You need to change `credentials: any` to match the input parameter signature for method `authorize`

```
(credentials: Record<never, string>, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">)
```

2. The return type of `authorize` needs to be `Awaitable<User>`. You are returning `user`.

Comment: can you please explain more about how to do the fixes? I did the above but it didn't work and I'm not sure the way I did it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I idea you need append infomation field to  credentials: {},
Example:

```javascript
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
...
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
    name: "Credentials",
    // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
    // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
    // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
    // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
    credentials: {
      username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
      password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
      // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
      const user = { id: "1", name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" }

      if (user) {
        // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
        return user
      } else {
        // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
        return null

        // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
      }
    }
  })
]
...
```

You can see it : https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials